# Integrating this function creates two inequivalent answers

Tags: calculus, integration

So, $$\int \tan(x)\sec^2(x)\ dx$$
is equal to: $$\frac{\tan^2(x)}{2}+C$$ when $u = \tan(x)$ and is equal to $$\frac{\sec^2(x)}{2}+C$$ when $u = \sec(x)$... Yet $$\frac{\tan^2(x)}{2}+C \neq \frac{\sec^2(x)}{2}+C$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$1+\tan^2 (x)=\sec^2 (x) $ thus both answers just differ by a constant hence they are equivalent.

Comment: Oh yeah totally forgot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They have the same derivative, $\mathbb tan(x) sec^2(x)$,  so they differ by a constant. ..